# I want to automate backups on an encrypted device; how can I soft reboot into TWRP so I don't have to enter my password?

Tags: backup, twrp

I've recently been exploring my options for automating backups, and I noticed [FlashFire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.flash) soft reboots into its environment, thereby eliminating the need to enter an encryption password. FlashFire has been extremely unreliable on my device, however, so I wonder: Is there any sort of command-line wizardry I can use to soft reboot into TWRP instead?

Comment: Did you try `reboot recovery`?

Comment: That's just a standard reboot to recovery.